# iReport Layout record . Any example?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *iReport 5* for all my reports. In one of my report, i need to display the records as like each section as follows

First Name : xxxxxxx

Last Name : xxxxxxx

Middle Name : xxxxxx

Age              : 40

---

First Name : yyyyyyy

Last Name : yyyyyyyy

Middle Name : yyyyyyyy

Age              : 30

---

First Name : zzzzzz

Last Name : zzzzz

Middle Name : zzzzz

Age              : 50

---

All the examples are showing how to display as follows

```
First Name    |      Last Name  |   Middle Name |   Age

xxxxxxxxx     | xxxxxxxxx   |   xxxxxxxxxxx |   40

yyyyyyyyy     | yyyyyyyyy   |   yyyyyyyyyyy |   30

zzzzzzzz      | zzzzzzzz    |   zzzzzzzzzzz |   50
```

Any help to identify which Report element can be used to display as per my requirement. I tried with table, list, etc. But not able to achieve the end result.

Comment: You can place *textFields* in *Detail* band as you want

Comment: [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) - you can start with studying this guide

Comment: Alex. Please let me know why down vote for me on this question. People may be expert, but we are beginners on this subject.

Comment: I voted for closing your question because you did not demonstrate any try to make this report by yourself. There are a lot samples for *JasperReports*, there a lot of posts on *SO* and so on. As for me, your question looks like: "Please, make this report for me".

Comment: Alex . You are wrong. There are thousands of questions and answers in the stackoverflow like my question. My Only question, why you are discouraging others by downvote. I am not such a guy, because of i am helping the new comers with my blog http://emrpms.blogspot.in/.  I strongly feel that you are misusing your reputation points to discourage others

Comment: Alex , please consider to remove the down vote. I am not able to ask valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iReport** allows you to drag and drop labels and text fields.

So just grab your labels from the *Column Header* area and drop them one beneath the other in the *Detail 1* area. Place the text fields next to them, the way you want them and you are done.

This layout of labels and fields:

[image]

Will produce the following report:

[image]

Comment: ok. What is the difference between using Table Element and Column Header and detail band ?

Comment: If the labels are in the Column Header, then they appear only once for a group of lines. If you place them in the Detail 1 area they appear once for every line. RTFM!